# Rails: When double clicked on a link, two pop-ups open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I got the following method in a controller (ProductController, for example).

```
  def show
    respond_with do |format|
      format.html do
        if request.xhr?
          @product = ...
          render :status => 200, :partial => 'products/show'
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When the user clicks on a product link, a pop-up will be opened with the product image and description.

The Problem: When the given user double-clicks on the product link, two pop-ups open. While debugging, I noticed that the `ProductController#show` method is called only once, but still two pop-ups are opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are sending request to server via ajax ? second request would be default behavior of your link. try this

```
$("a.your_link").click( function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // this will consume default functionality of your link 
   //now send request to server
   $.ajax(url: your_url).done( function(output){
     alert(data);
   });
});
```